# Сортировать коллекцию в обратном порядке android

Tags: java, android, listview, list, коллекции

Всем доброе время суток! У меня есть коллекция `List<Speakers>`, которую я добавляю в `listview`. Но при добавлении в контреллер у меня первый элемент коллекции становится последним на элементе. Как мне сделать обратную сортировку, чтобы он стал первым?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написать Comparator  и вызвать Collections.sort(yourCollection, Comparator)

```
Comparator<Speakers> REVERSE_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Speakers>(){

                @Override
                public int compare(Speakers o1, Speakers o2) {

                    if(условие более раннего элемента)
                    return 1;
                    else if(условие более позднего элемента)
                    return -1;
                    else return 0; // если элементы равны

                }
            };
    Collections.sort(List<Speakers>,REVERSE_COMPARATOR);
```

Comment: В идеале было бы привести минимальный пример компаратора

Comment: @A-Z можете показать пример пожалуйста, пока только в процессе изучения

Comment: Сейчас изменю ответ

Comment: @A-Z а фраза **условие более раннего элемента**, что означает? это надо сравнивать переменные о1 и о2 в условии?

Comment: Означает что по логике должно стоять раньше в коллекции,  я же не знаю что там за объект. То что должно стоять вначале 1, что в конце -1.

Comment: @A-Z в этом классе лежат поля id, name. Просто у меня пока мысль через цикл как-то перегонять чтобы получить нужный результат. Из приведенных мною параметров как это сделать в условиях? подскажите, плиз

Comment: Я же написал как, ничего прогонять не нужно, это реализовано в Collections.sort . Сортировка по какому полю идёт?

Comment: @A-Z по идее при добавлении я никакую сортировку сам не делаю. Но почему-то формируется так, что первый становится последним, второй предпоследним и т.д. А мне просто нужно перевернуть список вверх дном. Я даже не могу сказать какое поле тут полезнее будет, потому что id могут быть разные и не по порядку. Но два основных поля это как я писал  id, name. Остальные поля очень объемные.

Comment: Я тогда не понимаю что нужно. Есть какая-либо логика в сортировке или нет? Если логики никакой нет, то тогда добавлять в List можно через метод .add(0,Speakers) , ну тогда нужно использовать LinkedList, потому что в нём быстрее вставка в начало, чем в ArrayList, но это актуально только при большом количестве данных.

Comment: @АлександрМустафин если критериев сортировки нет, а надо тупо развернуть, то `Collections.reverse(list);`

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно переворачивать список, чтобы отображать элементы в `ListView` в обратном порядке. Нужно просто брать их в адаптере с конца:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
   return speakers.get(speakers.size() - position - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если желаете просто перевернуть список (чтобы первый элемент стал последним и т.д.), то используйте:

```
Collections.reverse(yourlist)
```